# Reverse a linked list recursively

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

This recursive calls `reverseList` on each node of the linked list. When returned from the function call, it changes the next link to the previous node.

```
public static Node reverseList(Node curNode , Node prevNode , Node reverseListHead)
{
    //empty list
    if(curNode == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    //node with single element
    if(curNode.next == null)
    {
        curNode.next = prevNode;
        reverseListHead = curNode;
        return reverseListHead;
    }
    reverseListHead = reverseList(curNode.next, curNode, reverseListHead);
    curNode.next = prevNode;
    return reverseListHead;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 3):

#### Only one argument needed

First of all, your third argument `reverseListHead` should be a local variable because it is never used before being set.

Next, if you change your algorithm slightly, you don't need the second argument either:

```
public static Node reverseList(Node head)
{
    // Empty list or list with one element.
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    Node second = head.next;
    Node reversedList = reverseList(second);

    // The second node is now the tail of the reversed list,
    // so when we append head to it, head becomes the new tail.
    second.next = head;
    head.next   = null;

    return reversedList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1 Algorithm**

You can do the same in linear time and space (recursion stack) with only one routine **`if`** and passing only two arguments to the actual algorithm routine. (See below.)

**2 Coding conventions**

In Java, it is advised to write

```
if (test()) {
    foo();
}
```

instead of

```
if (test()) 
{
    foo();
}
```

Also, you should have **one space** between **`if`** and the opening parenthesis of the condition.

You should have **one empty line** after the closing brace of an **`if`**, **`for`** or **`while`** and the subsequent statements in the same method. So, instead of

```
    ...
    return reverseListHead;
}
reverseListHead = reverseList(curNode.next, curNode, reverseListHead);
```

you should write

```
    ...
    return reversedListHead;
}

reverseListHead = reverseList(curNode.next, curNode, reverseListHead);
```

**3 API**

It would be nice if you had an "entry" method that asks only for one argument: the head of the list to reverse, and that would call a (**`private`**) implementation class method.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had the following in mind:

```
public class Node {

    final int datum;
    Node next;

    Node(final int datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the linked list starting from {@code head}. Returns the new
     * head node.
     * 
     * @param head the head of the linked list to reverse.
     * @return the new head node of the reversed list.
     */
    public static Node reverse(final Node head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final Node headNodeDummy = new Node(0);
        reverse(head, headNodeDummy);
        return headNodeDummy.next;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the linked list starting from {@code head}. Returns the new 
     * tail node of the reversed linked list, and sets 
     * {@code headNodeDummy.next} to the first node of the reversed list.
     * 
     * @param head          the beginning of the list to reverse.
     * @param headNodeDummy the node holding the head node of the result list.
     * @return              the last node of the reversed node.
     */
    private static Node reverse(final Node head, final Node headNodeDummy) {
        if (head.next == null) {
            headNodeDummy.next = head;
            return head;
        }

        final Node newTail = reverse(head.next, headNodeDummy);
        newTail.next = head;
        head.next = null;
        return head;
    }

    public static String toString(final Node head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return "[]";
        }

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[").append(head.datum);
        Node current = head.next;

        while (current != null) {
            sb.append(", ").append(current.datum);
            current = current.next;
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println("List lenght = 4:");
        Node n1 = new Node(1);
        Node n2 = new Node(2);
        Node n3 = new Node(3);
        Node n4 = new Node(4);

        n1.next = n2;
        n2.next = n3;
        n3.next = n4;

        System.out.println(toString(n1));
        n1 = reverse(n1);
        System.out.println(toString(n1));
        n1 = reverse(n1);
        System.out.println(toString(n1));

        System.out.println("List length = 2:");
        n1 = new Node(1);
        n2 = new Node(2);

        n1.next = n2;

        System.out.println(toString(n1));
        n1 = reverse(n1);
        System.out.println(toString(n1));
        n1 = reverse(n1);
        System.out.println(toString(n1));

        System.out.println("List length = 1:");

        n1 = new Node(1);

        System.out.println(toString(n1));
        n1 = reverse(n1);
        System.out.println(toString(n1));
        n1 = reverse(n1);
        System.out.println(toString(n1));

        System.out.println("List length = 0:");

        System.out.println(reverse(null));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.